# Join 2 table using like and get first record only

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have oracle sql query like below and i want to extract only one name matching like with t2 table.I am getting the records using the query but it is talking lot of time as i have more than 40 million names in t1 and .02 million in t2 table.

t1 data for col1:

```
N Wind Pudding Dr
Hasty Pudding Ln
Banana Pudding on the Go
Saint Barbaras R C Church
St Barbaras Rd
```

t2 data for col1:

```
Pudding
Barbaras
```

Query:

```
select t2.col1,t1.col1
from t1, t2
where t1.col1 like '% t2.col1 %';
```

output would be:

```
Pudding       N Wind Pudding Dr
Barbaras      Saint Barbaras R C Church
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Untested:

```
select t2.col1,
       (select t1.col1 from t1
        where t1.col1 like '%' || t2.col1 || '%''
        fetch first 1 row only)
from t2
```

Perhaps not the most efficient way...

Comment: This probably *is* the most efficient way, unless the OP plays with indexing to allow an index to be used for the `like` comparison.

Answer (score 0):

A few more options which select *any* `t1` table's row which matches `t2` column value.

One:

```
SQL> select max(t1.col), t2.col
  2  from t1 join t2 on instr(t1.col, t2.col) > 0
  3  group by t2.col;

MAX(T1.COL)                              COL
---------------------------------------- ----------
St Barbaras Rd                           Barbaras
N Wind Pudding Dr                        Pudding
```

Two:

```
SQL> select t1_col, t2_col
  2  from (select t1.col t1_col,
  3               t2.col t2_col,
  4               row_number() over (partition by t2.col order by null) rn
  5        from t1 join t2 on instr(t1.col, t2.col) > 0
  6       )
  7  where rn = 1;

T1_COL                                   T2_COL
---------------------------------------- ----------
Saint Barbaras R C Church                Barbaras
N Wind Pudding Dr                        Pudding

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something with CONTEXT index

```
CREATE INDEX text_indx  ON t1(col1) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CTXCAT;

SELECT t2.col1,t1.col1
  FROM t1, t2
 WHERE CONTAINS(t1.col1, t2.col1) > 0;
```